# logstash: clones with ruby script

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

I want to `clone` some events in a `logstash` pipeline, several times using the corresponding plugin.

So far I have been using an approach like the following:

(this is from my `logstash.conf`)

```
  clone {
      clones => [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
```

Is there a way to this in a more elegant manner to do this **programatically** using a ruby oneliner that returns a list with a given upper bound?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093690/logstash-use-ruby-code-inside-of-a-filter